# BFGminer running on GPU on Windows 7

Tags: gpu, bfgminer

I can't get the BFGminer to work on my Windows 7 machine. I've followed the instructions on https://www.btcguild.com/index.php?page=support. But when ever I run bfgminer.exe I get the following message at the top:

Waiting for devices; press 'M+' to add, or 'Q' to quit

I want to use my GPU, as I don't have any FPGA or ASIC devices yet. Can anyone help out?

Comment: I did this and it worked. Computer froze up and I had to force a restart. I'm assuming it hogged my GPU to death ;-;

Answer (score 6):

You can try to "auto-manually" add your GPUs to bfgminer by pressing `M` then `+` and then typing `auto`, or you can use the `-S opencl:auto` option when launching bfgminer.

NOTE: Not all graphics cards are compatible; various software is required (e.g., AMD APP sdk); it is not recommended to use GPUs for bitcoin mining with bfgminer.

According to [README.GPU](https://github.com/luke-jr/bfgminer/blob/bfgminer/README.GPU), the official documentation for bfgminer on github:

> By default, BFGMiner will NOT mine on any GPUs unless in scrypt mode. If you
>   wish to use your GPU to mine SHA256d (generally not a good idea), you can
>   explicitly enable it with the -S opencl:auto option.

To start scrypt mining with bfgminer and GPUs, use the `--scrypt` and `-S opencl:auto` options, but keep in mind that there are several other parameters to consider. See [README.scrypt](https://github.com/luke-jr/bfgminer/blob/bfgminer/README.scrypt) for additional details about scrypt mining configuration and optimization with GPUs.

Answer (score 3):

Put

```
start cmd /k bfgminer -S opencl:auto
```

in a batch file.

Answer (score 2):

CGMiner has removed GPU support, but BFGMiner has not. You can use an older version of CGMiner (i.e., v3.7.2) or GUIMiner or RPCMiner.A GPU is still useful for mining alternate coins such as litecoin, especially if you have a high-end AMD card.

Answer (score 0):

Sgminer-x64-5.3.4 is another good miner as well

Answer (score -1):

Throw a batchfile in the directory of your bfgminer with this:

```
start cmd /k bfgminer -S opencl:auto
```